# There was an error in your Gemfile after running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I tried running `rails s` and it gave me an error: `There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue`.

Here's the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'pg'
gem 'faker'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'fb_graph'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails', '= 0.3.4'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'thin'
gem 'google-analytics-rails'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'differ'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

group :development do
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'mail_safe', '0.3.1'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 3.0"
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'pry-nav'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :production do
  gem 'gmaps4rails'
end
```

Comment: Have you tried the `bundle install --verbose` command?

Comment: yes - edited the information above - I'm having suspicions that it's something to do with xcode. I just booted my environment from Time Machine and I think some things might be missing?

Comment: Just to be precise, `bundle install` is giving you an error @locoboy... it is in fact *not* successful.

Comment: Yes you're correct - I deleted my Gemfile.lock a little bit ago (edit's changed above)

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to require an exact version of haml-rails? That version (0.3.4) was released in October 2010. You might want to be a bit more flexible. For instance, `gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.3'`. Also, there's no need to list haml since it's a dependency of haml-rails.

Comment: Also, it might be completely unrelated, but it doesn't hurt to fix a few more things: **1.** Are you sure you need annotate, faker and thin in production? Most likely it's annotate and thin in dev only, faker in test and dev. **2.** You don't need to list rspec *and* rspec-rails, just remove rspec from the development group and leave rspec-rails where it is. **3.** Never use jquery-rails without specifying a version number, because things can seriously break from one version to another.

Comment: Also, you don't want mail_safe in your test environment. That one can safely be restricted to development.